# Move Legend Outside Plot AND Remove Double Legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to combine two pieces of code so that my plot's legend is outside the main plot AND there is only one set of labels. [See the plot below.] Right now I can either remove the double legend, or I can move it outside. I think I need a better understanding of how to combine all legend information into a single call to `ax.legend()`.

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x="surface_proteins", y="total_peaks", hue="pattern_geom",
             data=dfAnalysis, palette="Set3")
sns.swarmplot(x="surface_proteins", y="total_peaks", hue="pattern_geom",
             data=dfAnalysis, color = ".25", dodge=True)
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[:2], labels[:2])
ax.set_title('Total Number of Peaks Per Neuron')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Peaks')
ax.set_xlabel('Surface Proteins')
ax.legend(title='Pattern Geometry')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.savefig('PFP_PPN.'+timestamp+'.png',  bbox_inches='tight', dpi = 300, format = "png")
pdf.savefig(bbox_inches='tight')                                                
plt.close()
```

Swarmplot overlaid on Boxplot; results shown by category:

[image: Swarmplot overlaid on Boxplot; results shown by category]

Comment: You do 3 calls to `legend()`. Maybe you could leave out the last two, and just call `ax.legend(handles[:2], labels[:2], title='Pattern Geometry', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)`?

Comment: Thank you Johan! Earlier I had tried something similar but was getting an error. I tried what you said and it worked perfectly. I realized my mistake was putting title, bbox_to_anchor, etc. ahead of handles and labels.